# How to obtain documents based off comparing two fields Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently trying to write an app for an inventory management system and got a little stuck with one particular feature. I want to app to report to the user what stock is currently low in stock (upon request). I therefore added another field to be used in my product collection in firestore whereby the user can specify a minimum quantity on hand count. I want to know if it possible to obtain all the documents where (in my case) the current stock level is less than or equal to minimum stock level. In this case I have a single collection containing documents for each product, with each document containing various fields including the *minquantity* and *currentquantity* fields.

My only solution that I currently have is to obtain all the documents in the product collection and loop through every single one of them, but I am trying to improve the time it takes by minimizing the number of documents obtained.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to query Firestore in the way you want, you can't use a reference to a field in the value of a condition.

As usual when it comes to NoSQL databases, the solution is to add additional data to your data model to allow the use-case. In this case, consider adding a `quantitityBeforeNeedToReorder` field (there is probably a more concise name than that) and update that whenever you update the `currentQuantityField` too. With that field in place, your query is possible and quite simple.

You can even in security rules *ensure* that this `quantitityBeforeNeedToReorder` field has the correct value, as (unlike in queries) the security rules *can* do basic math between fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a rough idea on what you are saying, so thank you for the food for thought.